# does iOS have concept of trusted provider in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have read of the concept of a trusted provider in firebase. meaning that if email provider is gmail and google account is gmail and user logs in with them both that in firebase console google provider will be only as it is [trusted provider for the domain.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37663318/835883)

I have a gmail.com account created in a iphone and i created a password Provider in firebase console. so now
when i look up abc@gmail.com in firebase console it shows up as a email/password provider which is cool.

here is the proof:

[image]
then i used the same email abc@gmail.com and logged in with google, i went back to firebase after linking
and saw that abc@gmail.com NOW SHOWS two providers, google and email provider.

I did the same thing on android and there is only one provider, google.  what am i doing wrong ?

[many developers have quoted from a firebase doc](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6400716)

> You can configure whether users can create multiple accounts that use the same email address, but are linked to different sign-in methods. For example, if you don't allow multiple accounts with the same email address, a user cannot create a new account that signs in using a Google Account with the email address ex@gmail.com if there already is an account that signs in using the email address ex@gmail.com and a password.

does this apply when its from iOS ?  is this rule still valid ?

further info:

i am using single provider account:

[image]

if your not able to explain any of that, just explain what scenario firebase console can have google and email provider listed at the same time using a gmail account. i thought it should be google only. Please explain the image of the firebase console showing both google and email provider listed at the sametime for gmail account.

Comment: Explain the exact steps how you created the initial user. Did you sign in with Google and then add a password to the user? Did you verify the email of the user first and then add the google provider? It is not clear how you got to the user with both providers linked. The details here are important to explain this.

Comment: ok i'll do it again on monday and let you know